# Ubuntu boots to command line after kernel error

Tags: 14.04, command-line, kernel, virtualbox, software-center

I was attempting to install Windows 7 in Virtual Box with Ubuntu 14.04 as the host OS.

While so doing, a kernel error message came up.

Suddenly, the terminal and software center were gone. I managed to recover them, but then the Ubuntu Software Center asked for a reboot so that the changes made to update an application could take effect.

After rebooting, my GUI was completely gone.

Now, whenever I boot Ubuntu I just get dumped at a command prompt. After loging into the CMD, it shows this message:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade: 4: /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade: lsb_release: not found
```

FYI, I have an AMD graphics card.

**What happened, and how can I repair my system?**

Comment: What exactly was the kernel error?

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to boot off a USB to reinstall the operating system? The error message you are receiving is about the Message of the Day, which wouldn't affect the issue you are having at all.

have you tried running the update through terminal?

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Download from here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-release-upgrader_0.220.1.tar.gz

Unzip, open terminal and go to the directory location, Type:

```
./do-release-upgrade
```

Done.

Source:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/1:0.220.1
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1306673